# USB3--> ethernet --> USB3 extension

Tags: usb, usb-device

I'm interested in greatly extending (~100m) a USB3 connection for a robotics project. Does anybody have any suggestions? I would love to be able to go:

USB3 hub with several clients ==> some device ==> ethernet ==> USB3 host computer

But it seems that's not possible with USB3-ethernet adapters.

Is a software or hardware based solution using Linux possible?

Comment: In general USB to Ethernet adapters do not extend USB, they provide Ethernet via a USB port.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Unix or Linux. It might be a better fit for [Robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) or [su].

Comment: I think it's off-topic here, but the "more expensive hardware" is probably what you're looking for. It'll be cheaper if you only need USB2. Or change your design to use some signaling that was intended to go longer ranges (Ethernet, serial, etc.)

Comment: It's easy to do that with [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) and some embedded system that runs Linux and has USB3 port(s) at one end. And I'd consider this solution very much on-topic.

Comment: @dirkt If you think you're able to reword the question to direct solutions towards the kind of answers that are on topic here in a way that still fits the OPs criteria I think it would make sense to reopen. However, as the question is stated now it sounds like a better fit for [superuser](https://superuser.com/) in my opinion.

Comment: For WIndows, Silex Gigbie USB3 over IP ($127) might work, but it doesn't have a Linux driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they've updated to USB 3 or not... I've used some "100 foot extenders" (not sure on brand, on vacay until next week and the equipment is at work) that worked, but they required power to actually send a usable signal more than 20 feet or so.  Also, they are/were a 1 to 1 device extender, couldn't have a hub at the remote end.  But that was all 5+ years ago.

If I needed to do the same today (it was using USB webcams in a zoo) I'd use a Raspberry Pi with a cam and send the data via network and use wireless, etc.